# What is the best way to let someone test your webapp

Tags: python, django, testing, user-testing

I've been creating an webapp (just for learning purposes) using python django, and have no intention in deploying it. However, is there a way to let someone else, try the webapplication, or more precisely: Is it possible to somehow test the webapp on another computer. I tried to send det source code (and the whole folder), to another computer, installed virtual environment, activated it, and tried to runserver. However, I always get runtimeerror:maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp. Is there any other way around it?

Comment: deploy it on an AWS or GCE instance and let a few people try it out. You can then take it down

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngrok -- https://ngrok.com/ -- to create a public URL to your local server for testing, and then give that URL to people so they can try your webapp.

Comment: I am also in love with ngrok definitely recommending this jewel!

Comment: THX! That was awesome!!

Comment: I am using postgresql, how do you make that work with ngrok? Im am not able to connect to my database

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me) to easily share a web service on your local development without deploying the code in the server.

Install the localtunnel

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

Start a webserver on some local port (eg http://localhost:8000) and use the command line interface to request a tunnel to your local server

```
lt --port 8000
```

You will receive a url, for example https://xyz.localtunnel.me, that you can share with anyone for as long as your local instance of lt remains active. Any requests will be routed to your local service at the specified port.